# KVM 3.1.1 installation

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kernel, linux-kvm, kernel-module

I have a requirement to install KVM 3.1.1 on RHEL7 or 8.

When I am checking I found that qemu-kvm is automatically installed on RHEL8 and the version is 4.2.

It would be great if anyone can share the valuable input for me to install kvm 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You would use the package manager `yum` to search for all packages containing `kvm` From the package names you can choose the correct one, and install it also using `yum` Then the package will be installed. If you have anything to input with your boss, you could suggest virtualbox, which is a GUI VM program. But if you're just making server VMs, then KVM is probably better.

Check [here.](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/how-manage-packages)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have installed using yum but my requirement is to install kvm 3.1.1.
Along with RHEL 8 kvm version is 4.x I tried to downgrade RHEL 8 to 7 but in RHEL 7 KVM version is 1.x. Is there any other way to install KVM 3.1.1 along with libvirt